# How to wrap content with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use wrap around the content with the placeholder div using jQuery?

So I can turn this:

```html
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

Into this:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
  <div class="content">Abcd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be more specific: Do you want it to wrap all the div elements until div with class "placeholder"? And if there is no more "placeholder" div then to wrap all the divs? Or do you want to wrap each 3 HTML elements? There are too many interpretations for your question...

Comment: Not each three elements, there could be any number. The only variable is that there would be a placeholder tag. I've modified the example to make it clearer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this with jQuery 1.4:

```
$('.placeholder').each(function(){
     $(this).nextUntil('.placeholder').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
});
```

jQuery 1.4 added the nextUntill function